# Photo Competition June: Baby or Juvenile Animals in TGO

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

**Rules that are always applicable are as follows:**

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per contest**
2. Post only photos taken by yourself/person with you
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content

**Rules for June are as follows:**

1. Baby or Juvenile Animals - **Baby or juvenile animals in TGO**, alone or with their mothers or with other animals, but focus on the baby or juvenile. **The contest excludes house pets and caged animals.** People allowed, but should be ancillary to the main subject
2. The contest will last the whole month of June and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself
3. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken

**Rule #4, Added on 06/26: Any future downvotes disallowed.  All the entries are legitimate according to the rules, thus there is no basis for "disagreeing" with any of the entries.**  No entry is "not useful" or "not helpful".  **________________________________________________________________________**

Suggest a theme for the next contest.

1. Leave a single comment below in the format THEME - ONE SENTENCE DESCRIPTION
2. **I added suggestions from previous months.**
3. Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good Luck!

Comment: @Sue I am going to change it now to "baby or juvenile", is that adequate? I was thinking of doing that anyway.  Thanks for reminding me.  I can't think of anything beyond that.  One really can't ask a bunny if it has attained puberty.  Also excluded caged animals per Willeke.

Comment: Suggestion in Next theme: A tree (not a plant) and a man-made building in the same frame.

Comment: Weda Pashi: Shades of sky -- no artificial objects in the frame

Comment: JJJ: Extreme Weather

Comment: fredsbend: Bird's Eye View -- Photo taken from far above, feet not on the ground.

Comment: Nature Reclaiming - Lone man-made structures (outside of cities) in some stage of decay, being "reclaimed" by nature

Comment: Close up - Macro photography, showing small things large

Comment: That's *my* girl! - Animals acting out mating behavior and courtship. Fighting, posturing, dancing, etc. Mating specifically is not really the target.

Comment: If we're chiming in with subject suggestions: "Dangerous **little** animals (wombats, skunks, possums, racoons, no bobcats)" - well, bobcats and tigers if you want, it's your life. Must *obviously* be wild and in their native habitat, also must be clear how close you are; closest wins, snarling and pouncing for a bonus. As per prior comment, no rabbits.

Comment: @Rob What prior comments about rabbits?

Comment: @ab2 [TVTropes - Arson, Murder & Jaywalking](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArsonMurderAndJaywalking), the opposite of [Clue, Evidence, & the Smoking Gun](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClueEvidenceAndASmokingGun) - not everything translates from English.

Comment: Hi ab2! I just noticed (8/29/19) your additional "rule" disallowing downvotes. (I had already posted my photo, otherwise I wouldn't have.) That can't be a "rule" because it breaks SE policy. The voting system is foundational, and trying to get around it by disallowing downvotes isn't right. Photos are "answers" and people can choose how to vote just like any other "answers," even if they meet the contest criteria. Meta's public, and is here for people to learn how the site and network function. We can't set a bad example. By we I include myself, I'm not picking on you!

Comment: @Sue Charlie is running the photo contest.  I just stepped in for one month when he was too busy, so your comment really should be sent to him.  But,  rules are not sacred.   "Disallowed" means "downvote if you must, but the person running the contest will not count downvotes."  Then if enough people object that this violates SE,  the contest, IMO, will become a mess.  It looks as though we both are up very late!

Comment: ab2, thanks for this and for being so kind!! I appreciate the explanation!. I was up late indeed!! I thought you ran this yourself, it was nice of you to help @Charlie. I'll check his out instead!! I hope I conveyed that it wasn't personal! In case you're wondering, I haven't downvoted!

Comment: Toby S: Activity -- Person or persons interacting with the natural environment is some way – 2 votes; Subject for August

Comment: ab2: Water in TGO -- Fresh or Salt; Still or Running or Falling or Frozen. People allowed, but focus should be on the water feature, not the people. Animals welcome. No artificial water -- e.g., no swimming pools; 4 votes; Subject for September

Comment: Close up - Macro photography, showing small things large – helm -- 6 votes; Subject for July

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Northern Sweden, August 2014. The other reindeer that didn't see us peeking around the rock.

[image]

Comment: Lovely! But I can't find the other reindeer.  Could you circle it?

Comment: The other one was never close enough to be on the same photo, but there's a photo of it here (including the story behind it): https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1412/15870

Answer (score 10):

[image: Baby Wallaby]

This is a baby wallaby with its mother. I took this photo while visiting the [Kuranda Koala Garden](https://www.koalagardens.com/) near Cairns, Australia.

Date: July 15, 2015

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's breathtaking!

Comment: How did you remember it since my ping was a long time ago?

Comment: A few people starred [that message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=50121906#50121906) so it was present on the right side of the chat window for a few weeks

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Juvenile marine iguanas climbing on what is presumably the mother.
Picture taken in December 2016 in Puerto Ayora, Galápagos Islands.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is the only sea foraging marine lizard. When it comes to seeing unique species, the Galapagos sure doesn't disappoint. An item on my bucket list is to sail along the western coast of the Americas, starting in San Diego with Galapagos being a major stop.

Answer (score 9):

Three young elephants following the safari group in
[Kaziranga National Park, India](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kaziranga+National+Park/@26.573099,93.1804207,17892m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x3744412d379f65df:0x8b2b74b6e7c99458!8m2!3d26.577531!4d93.171122) in June 2018.

A bonus is the baby rhino with its mother in the background.

[image: a flock of dumbos]
(unedited)

Answer (score 9):

This one's a surprise treat, just minutes ago.

[image: Fawn 2019]

## The Wobbly Fawn

June 20, 2019, Northwest USA.

I think he's a late comer, as the fawns are all a month or two old now. I guess he's only a week or less. He could barely walk, and didn't even notice me until I was 10 feet from him.

Comment: Live long and prosper, wobbly fawn!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

This is a baby red squirrel born in our back yard in Massachusetts, USA. It's so small that the whole thing fits on a regular sized hose nozzle!

I took the picture on July 8, 2017.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Killdeer Fledgling]

## [Killdeer fledgling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killdeer)

Taken June 7, 2019 in Northwestern USA.

These birds are fun to watch. They nest and fledge in open fields, where both parents spend 99% of the time with the chicks. They're easy to find but hard to photograph because they are very fast even at only a week old. When you get close to hatchlings or fledglings one or both of the parents tries to get your attention by pretending to be injured, laying flat on the ground making an injured call, and flailing their wings. If you draw close, it jumps up and flies another forty feet away from the chicks and does it again. It can be quite a show.

---

<sup>[Originally submitted picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RbAZ.jpg) was not as good, which was taken only an hour earlier. I got lucky and got this new picture of a much younger fledgling that I could actually catch.</sup>

Comment: This is the best picture I could get with my phone. As I said, they're very fast. I was running through the field snapping shots like a crazy man. Really should have tried for a picture a month ago. They were less than half the size then, and easier to corner.

Comment: Actually, this topic is at about a month late. Most newborn things are quite grown now.

Comment: Baby animals never go out of style.  We can do them again next year, but earlier.

Comment: Can you update the phrase "this one is at least 30 days old".

Answer (score 6):

[image: baby Egyptian goose]
Photo taken in Hydepark, London, UK, 4 May 2013.
Free to use.

I am not sure about the kind of goose but I have an other photo of this same young with an adult bird [an Egyptian goose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_goose), so I assume that they are the same kind.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

These cute-little Bar-headed goose would follow their mother everywhere.

Picture taken on July 2018, at [Tso Moriri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tso_Moriri) 4,522 m/14,836 ft.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Juvenile bobcat I had cross a biking trail in front of me in Colorado last week.

Comment: They tell me there's bobcats where I live. I think they're lying.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Juvenile lion after having wildebeest for breakfast, Serengeti National Park, Tanzania, 2012-08-31

Answer (score 5):

[image: Unidentified Juvenile Skink]

## Unidentified Juvenile Skink

Taken May, 2019 in Northwestern USA.

When I was a kid turning up rocks every three days, I would find one of these every once in a while. I didn't realize they were juveniles until I found this monster last month:

[image: Unidentified Adult Skink]

Both were just chilling in my garden, eating bugs and grubs. I found the juvenile again a week later (I assume the same one because he was in the same garden shed) and he was twice as big and shedding skin. I didn't photograph it though.

Comment: Is than skink poop on your finger?

Comment: @ab2 Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Blue Jay Fledgling]

## Blue Jay Fledgling

Taken April, 2018 in Northwestern USA

Comment: What color!  Just a reminder, each contestant is limited to five entries per contest.  (The two skinks count as only one.)

Comment: @ab2 Yes, it's a beautiful bird, which makes up for its horrible squawk. This was taken with a Samsung Galaxy S8.

Comment: This is gorgeous, and really helpful to me! We have a large number of blue jays and similar sized birds here in Massachusetts, Northeast USA.  I see juveniles so I know they're breeding in our trees, but I've never seen a fledgling! So many birds are born without a lot of color. Now that I know these guys are already blue when they fledge, I'll spend more time looking!

Comment: @Sue With this particular species, the only thing that will change with this pictured bird is that the head will darken to nearly black.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Mallard ducklings I found last year in a city pond.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Nestling sparrow preparing to fledge]

This is a nestling house sparrow just getting ready to go out into the world. Daddy's keeping a watchful eye from a tree by the box. I took the picture two days ago, on June 11, 2019. This baby wasn't quite ready, and has spent the last few days going to the entrance and back, and retreating into the nest for the night. Daddy is coming and going. (By this point in the process, Mom has moved on, presumably to build the next nest. Daddy will do all the care now and for the first few weeks after the birds fledge, until they can be on their own.)

At any time in the nesting process, humans can bring danger and cause stress for the birds. Getting too close during this phase can literally mean the difference between life and death for the whole family.

Last year we scared a nestling out of the nest just before fledging time. It bumped into a table and perished. It was heartbreaking!

We've kept our distance, and don't know the status of this or the other potential birds in that nest.

This picture was taken by me, using a zoom lens on an inexpensive camera from inside the house by a window. That's why it's so blurry!

Comment: A pretty ordinary picture is made so much more interesting by your wonderful explanation - thank you!

Comment: Interestingly, we have swallows that like to nest *directly on the motion-activated bulkhead light* in our porch (i.e. the nest sits right on the transparent cover).  The light comes on every time someone walks in or out of the building.  You'd think that that would seriously disturb them, but they've been coming back ever since we built the porch three or four years ago.  Adaptation in the natural world is an amazing thing...

Comment: That's cool! Last year a robin was building a nest on ours, but I think she may have been inexperienced. She laid out the long strands of wheat but didn't weave them. They kept falling off in the rain and she eventually gave up! We felt bad for her! We have fledglings  near the area this year but I don't see a nest.

Answer (score 4):

Dangerous little animals - distance ~5 ft from cellphone in hand, seven from my face.

[image: Skunk, two views.]

First view from behind and second shot a few seconds later from the side. Yesterday, Vancouver BC Canada, 0200 hours.

Comment: *All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.*  What is this thing?  Doesn't look like a badger, but it's not like anything else I've ever seen.  Can you tell us anything else about it (e.g. whether the adults look similar or not)?  Thanks.

Comment: @TobySpeight https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skunk

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere along Cha-Am beach. Picture taken in July of 2017.

I'm not sure what we're seeing here but I like to think the larger shell contains the parent animal and the smaller one (on top in the smaller shell) is their offspring. 
[image]