# Photo Competition: September - Water

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per contest.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself/person with you.
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content
5. Only upvotes count towards winning.

---

Rules for September are as follows:

1. **Water - Water with or without people. Water can be liquid (fresh or salt) or frozen; can be still, running or falling. No swimming pools or hot tubs, please unless there is something TGO-ish about them -- e.g., an alligator in the hot tub. :)**
2. The contest will last the whole month of September and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
3. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

---

Suggest a theme for the next contest.

1. Leave a **single** comment below in the format
     THEME - ONE SENTENCE DESCRIPTION
2. Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good luck!

Comment: See [June contest, here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/photo-competition-june-baby-or-juvenile-animals-in-tgo) for all the contest suggestions previously listed.

Comment: OOPS! -- Somebody being clumsy in TGO.  Should be funny, or, if not hilarious, at least mildly amusing.

Comment: Enclaves of TGO in Large Cities -- not necessarily restricted to the wilder parts of large parks.  Be creative.  No automobiles in the photos, and preferably no asphalt.

Comment: Charlie B: Underwater -- At least the camera must have been underwater when the shot was taken. The photographer does not have to be underwater, but nice if he/she was ---  1 vote in June List

Comment: Proposed by WedaPashi -- A tree (not a plant) and a man-made building in the same frame --- 3 votes in June List

Comment: Proposed by helm:   Nature Reclaiming - Lone man-made structures (outside of cities) in some stage of decay, being "reclaimed" by nature --- 4 votes in June List

Comment: Proposed by Dynat: Opposites occurring in TGO ---  1 vote in June List

Comment: Proposed by JJJ: Extreme Weather --- 2 votes in June List

Comment: Proposed by fredsbend -- That's my girl! - Animals acting out mating behavior and courtship. Fighting, posturing, dancing, etc. Mating specifically is not really the target --- 1 vote in June list

Comment: Proposed by fredsbend --- Bird's Eye View -- Photo taken from far above, feet not on the ground --- 2 votes in June List

Comment: Proposed by WedaPashi --- Shades of sky -- no artificial objects in the frame --- 2 votes in June list

Comment: Proposed by Rob --- "Dangerous little animals (wombats, skunks, possums, racoons, no bobcats)" - well, bobcats and tigers if you want, it's your life. Must obviously be wild and in their native habitat, also must be clear how close you are; closest wins, snarling and pouncing for a bonus. --- 2 votes in June List

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: waterfall]

A cheese cube, good camera, rain and waterfalls... what else should one desire for on a monsoon trek?

This was clicked July last year, en-route a trek, in a stream where we all slipped and fell countless times without frowning about it :)

Place: Enroute Bhivgad fort, about a 80 miles from Mumbai, India.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Swimming on Crowlin Mor]

Swimming in [a small lochan](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=57.3431389&mlon=-5.8335139&zoom=14) on the Crowlin Isles, north-west Scotland; Friday 7th May 2010.

I'm quite fond of the shape of the ripples made around the swimmer here.

Answer (score 8):

[image: ed t]

Kayaking in the Adriatic Sea. [Pula, Croatia](https://goo.gl/maps/ex9NH67oQXmKYDvc6). On 06.04.2019.

Answer (score 8):

Rime ice on a fencepost somewhere on the slopes of [Great How](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=54.4179819&mlon=-3.2275868&zoom=14), Cumbria, on Tuesday 8th January 1991.  Apologies for the amount of dust and dirt on the negative!

[image: rime ice]

Comment: It's nice to see a non-digital photo :-)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Love for the locks.

Aug 4, 2018 - End of a kayaking trip along the Grand Union Canal in Buckinghamshire, England.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Hello from Below.

So this was August 10th-13th 2018 - we went scuba diving for the first time in the North Sea off the NE English / SE Scottish coastlines. We had the good fortune to be able to get this still from one of our videos with the gopro photo/still option. 18m down in the cold waters was a lot of fun. Water technically as we were fully surrounded by it.

(see below, not entirely sure which vid it was from as we ended up with at least 5 videos)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbTcGuKNmt0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YslyLNGemRY

Answer (score 7):

Filtering water - Greenland (Arctic Circle Trail) end of July.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: water coming over a weir]
The weir and bridge over the Thames at Hambleden Lock, near Henley on Thames, UK, 13 July 2019.

Comment: My computer went into some kind of snit, and I "fixed" it by turning it off and then on.

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere in the Solent. Single class (Jeanneau Sunfast 37's) in 2004. Taken by me just after repairing our broken foresail furler!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Grand Canyon mile 62. Little Colorado River, AZ. Jan 6, 2019

[image]

**Some more info about the picture/location:**
The LCR is a tributary to the Colorado River in that runs through the Grand Canyon. We got lucky and timed it after the first snowstorm of the year. Winter 2018 was one of the driest in Grand Canyon history, and so being the morning after the snowstorm with the temperature staying low, we got the snow covered canyon walls with the icy blue to green transition of the water. Normally the little Colorado river is brown with the silty water that feeds the Colorado River needed minerals and gives it the iconic brown color. This morning was day 4 of 19 down the 227 miles from Lee's Ferry to Diamond Creek. We had cold temps (~5°F first night) but had a trip of a lifetime. The picture itself is a 50MP composite made of 30 images. Taken on a Nikon D600 with a 18-35mm D lens.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Taken late August 2019 by myself at Niagra Falls, Canada

Answer (score 3):

[image: a shipping canal going out into the sea]
This is the Noordzeekanaal (shipping canal from Amsterdam to the North Sea) with the complex of locks and the sea in the distance.
Photo taken from a plane, coming in for landing at Amsterdams Airport Schiphol, 21 July 2019.

The towns in the picture are Beverwijk and IJmuiden, as well as Tata steel factory grounds, the Netherlands.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Mountain whitefish, Jackson hole, this summer.

Answer (score 3):

[image: the surf with the sky above]
I took this photo today, 13 September 2019, on the beach in Wijk aan Zee, the Netherlands. This photo stood out because of the reflections in the still water before the surf.

The waves were not very high but they seem higher because of the camera position.